# Celery group not executing tasks when number of tasks in the group is greater than number of CPU cores

Tags: django, redis, celery

I have a `django` project in which `celery` is configred with `redis` as `broker` and `backend` both. I have a group of tasks which is executed asynchronously and I use the `save` and `restore` method of `GroupResult` so that I can update the progress of tasks on frontend using ajax. This all works correctly when the `group` size is 1 less than the number of CPU cores. Whenever the group size greater than or equal to number of CPU cores, all the tasks are received by celery and nothing happens next unless I restart celery. All tasks are completed but I have to restart it.

My celery settings are as follows:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
```

I have used `Rabbitmq` also in place of redis as Broker but the same thing happens in case of Rabbitmq also. Why is this happening? I am not able to find any thing on this issue.

Comment: Not sure without seeing your code but from what you've said with the GroupResult you are spawning off other tasks thus for example you have task G1 which spawns T1 T2 T3.  If you have 4 workers thats fine as you have 4 tasks.  If you have 3 workers it will only run tasks G1 T1 and T2.  T3 never gets run thus holding the workers executing the other tasks

Comment: But after execution of G1 T1 and T2 it should execute T3 as the tasks are queued. But any one of them is not getting executed. I can see the queue length which shows 4 in case of our example. If I increase the concurrency to a larger value than 4  it works fine. I don't know why this is happening? I am using pickle method for serialization I have to pass class objects to tasks, can that be a cause of this problem?